# Python program to scramble MP3 audio

Tags: python, beginner, random, audio, pyqt

I'm super new to coding. I had a random idea in the car to make this application in order dive head first into learning to code.

This is an app to take an MP3 file, "shred it" into pieces (creates 1 second mp3 files temporarily), then randomize the pieces, and then compiles a new MP3 file with all the "shreds" in a randomized order. In order to accomplish this, I used my very limited knowledge and so my code probably isn't written well.

Is there anything that you might change about my code? Any critiques will be helpful. I learned and put this together in about 10 hours. (I'm really enjoying this!)

A future goal I have is to make this functionality web-accessible so that my friends can use it without downloading executable code.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import random
import os
from glob import glob
from string import ascii_lowercase
from random import choice, randint, random
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class shredder(QWidget):
   def __init__(self, parent = None):
      super(shredder, self).__init__(parent)

      self.setMinimumSize(350, 100)
      #self.setFixedWidth(350)
      #self.setFixedHeight(100)

      layout = QVBoxLayout()
      self.btn = QPushButton("Load MP3")
      self.btn.clicked.connect(self.getfile)

      layout.addWidget(self.btn)
      self.le = QLabel("File Location:")
      self.le.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

      layout.addWidget(self.le)
      self.btn1 = QPushButton("Shred")
      self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.shred)
      layout.addWidget(self.btn1)
            
      self.setLayout(layout)
      self.setWindowTitle("MP3Shredder")
    

   def getfile(self):
      global filepath
      filepath, _filter = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open MP3 File', 
         '',"MP3 (*.mp3)")
      if filepath:
            self.le.setText("File Location: "+filepath)      


   def shred(self):
        global filepath
        
        try:
            filepath
        except NameError:
            self.le.setText("You Must First Load A MP3 File To Shred!") 
        else:
            #importing file with pydub from location by giving its path
            song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(filepath)
            #creates an MP3 object with mutagen from file location and saves it as variable
            audio = MP3(filepath)
            audio_info = audio.info
            length = int(audio_info.length)
            hours, mins, seconds = audio_duration(length)
            print('Total Duration Of Song: {}:{}:{}'.format(hours, mins, seconds))
            print("In Seconds: " + str(audio.info.length))
            print("Creating " + str((audio.info.length//1)+1) +" shreds.")

            os.makedirs(os.path.join(r"C:\mp3shredder"), exist_ok=True)
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(r"C:\mp3shredder\temp"), exist_ok=True)

            print("Shredding...")
            
            #split sound in 1-second slices and export
            for i, chunk in enumerate(song[::1000]):
                with open(r"C:\mp3shredder\temp\piece%s.mp3" % i, "wb") as f:
                    chunk.export(f, format="mp3")
    
            path = (r"C:\mp3shredder\temp")
            files = os.listdir(path)

            for index, file in enumerate(files):
               os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, ''.join([choice(ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(randint(5, 8))])+".mp3"))
  
            print("Shredding Complete!")

            print("Gluing...")

            shredded_pieces = [AudioSegment.from_mp3(mp3_file) for mp3_file in glob(r"C:\mp3shredder\temp\*.mp3")] 

            glue_it_back = AudioSegment.empty()
            for song in shredded_pieces:
                glue_it_back += song
            
            filedir = os.path.dirname(filepath)
            filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
            
            glue_it_back.export(filedir + "/" + "SHREDDED_" + filename, format="mp3")
            
            dir = (r"C:\mp3shredder\temp")
            for f in os.listdir(dir):
                os.remove(os.path.join(dir, f))
    
            os.rmdir(dir)
    
            print("Gluing Complete!")
            print("Created: " + filedir + "/" + "SHREDDED_" + filename)
            
            self.le.setText("Created: " + filedir + "/" + "SHREDDED_" + filename)
            os.startfile(filedir)

# function to convert the information into 
# some readable format
def audio_duration(length):
    hours = length // 3600  # calculate in hours
    length %= 3600
    mins = length // 60  # calculate in minutes
    length %= 60
    seconds = length  # calculate in seconds
    
    return hours, mins, seconds  # returns the duration
   

def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = shredder()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Just... Why? In my imagination the output would sound gruesome.

Comment: @Reinderien What, you've never wanted to BOGO sort a song?

Comment: @Reinderien obviously you can apply a metric to the 1-second samples, sort in order of this metric, and then cut the last 30% out to make a better song

Comment: I think you'll be interested to learn your idea is like granular synthesis. This is a fantastic presentation on the topic. https://youtu.be/FEK8Ggg2xxQ

Comment: I like the idea, there's a lot of fun to be had in this space. You might like checking out Adam Edmond on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AL1q-zZWViM

Answer (score 20):

- Consider what happens if a user closes the "Load MP3" dialog without picking a file. In that case, `filepath` would get set to `""`. The label would not change, but should the user press the "Shred" button anyway, we would try to import a file called `""` (since the `filepath` variable exists, we don't get that `NameError`) which would presumably not go terribly well
- I'm not sure why we write the chunks to temporary files only to read them again? It seems like it'd be simpler to do something like this:

```
glued_song = AudioSegment.empty()

for chunk in random.sample(song[::1000], song.duration_seconds):
    glued_song += chunk
```

- Should you need to keep the temp files, I would advise using the `tempfile` module to create it in a more secure and portable manner, in a standard location
- You only seem to use `mutagen` to get the duration of the original track. Since `pydub` supports getting the duration of `AudioSegment`s, (using `song.duration_seconds`), taking on a whole other dependency just for that seems unnecessary
- Instead of a global variable, it may be neater to have the currently selected file path be a property of the `shredder` class - you could set it like `self.filepath = None` in the `__init__`, and then access it as `self.filepath` in `getfile` and `shred`
- I do think allowing the user to pick the output file name might be a desirable feature
- Finally, I'm not a big fan of some of the variable names in use here:

  - `shredder`, as a class name, would typically be written like `Shredder`
  - `btn` and `btn1` tells me very little about what those buttons are. `load_button` and `shred_button`, for example, would be more descriptive
  - Similarly, I have *no* clue what `le` means. I might go for something like `path_label` or `selection_label` instead
  - `getfile` is two words - `get_file`. Or perhaps `select_file`, or `pick_file`, to more clearly indicate a choice is being made
  - `song` is re-used for different purposes in the same method, which might get confusing
  - `glue_it_back` sounds like less like a *thing* and more like something you *do* - it's a fine name for a function, but for an object I'd prefer something like `glued_song`, or even just `result`

Comment: You are so helpful and gracious! This has helped me tremendously!

Answer (score 16):

There is quite some room for improvement, both in the overall architecture and style and in the logic that you use:

## Architecture and style

### Separate logic from presentation

You have a single class handling both the logic ("shredding" the audio file) and the presentation (the PyQt widgets). This makes testing harder, as you can't call your `shred` from a test runner without building a GUI, and reviewing more painful than it should: I am not willing to install a 250+ MiB package (PyQt5, in this case) just for a review.

In your case, `shred` could be a standalone method, taking an `AudioFragment` as argument and returning another `AudioFragment`.

Also, you print a bunch of things to the console while processing audio files, not only mixing logic and presentation, but mixing multiple kind of presentation -- GUI and console. I get that it can be useful while developing and debugging, but you should consider using a logger instead.

### Don't use globals

You use a global variable for `filepath`. Globals are usually considered to be bad practice, and while they can have legitimate uses, this is not one. It may work for now, but it's a foot gun: you could change the file path from anywhere else in the code, including outside the GUI class and have the GUI and the internal state out of sync, creating issues for the users. This is especially true given the generic variable name.

In your case, you could keep track of the path using an instance parameter (`self.filepath`) or pass it around method as an argument.

### Naming

Use meaningful variable names. You mostly do, but the UI widgets names carry no information, see `btn` and `btn1` for example. `load_file_button` and `shred_button` would be much more descriptive names.

Imagine working on a slightly more complex UI, you would lose tracks of what widget does what *very* quickly with your current naming.

### Documentation

Your code contains no documentation. Docstrings would be very useful in understanding what the program does, especially for the `shred` method, which does something pretty unique to your program.

## Logic

### Don't write to disk if you can avoid it

There is no reason to write the song chunks to disk in your case. You could instead slice the song into chunks and put them into an array, shuffle them with `random.shuffle` and splice them in a new `AudioFragment` all in memory.

### Side effects

What if the user has some personal data in a directory unfortunately named `C:\mp3shedder\temp`? It gets nuked when running your program.

If you do have to write to and delete from disk (which you don't, in your case), you should probably be much more careful with how you do it.

### Relative over absolute paths

You use hardcoded, absolute paths, which is more likely to introduce side effects when reading, writing and deleting from disk.

Comment: In your `Side Effects`, you could point OP to the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) standard library module, which is specifically designed to create temporary files and directories. With a hard coded temp path also comes OS dependence which you could highlight in your answer

Answer (score 11):

First off, this is quite an interesting project for a beginner, well done on getting it working. Other people have mentioned a lot of the issues with our code style, however to expand on a few points:

### General PEP-8

[PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) is the standard style recommendation for Python. In it, it includes things like how many blank lines, how much indentation, recommendations for variable naming and casing.

There are linters ([Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/), [Pylint](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) and others) which check your code against PEP-8 and issue useful warnings. In your case there are several simple and obvious things.

#### Whitespace

PEP-8 recommends multiples of 4 spaces for indentation, 2 blank lines between top-level functions/classes, 1 blank line between internal functions.

Operators are surrounded by whitespace.

```
x = a + b
```

Keyword parameters are not surrounded by whitespace.

```
def func(a, b=None):
```

Commas are followed by spaces.

```
('A', 'B', 'C')
```

#### Imports

You import `random` twice, once as a plain library

```
import random
```

and once specific elements from `random`

```
from random import choice, randint, random
```

Which actually causes a name collision between `random` the library and `random.random` the function. Obviously not great.

It is also good practice to put Python standard library imports before general ones.

Importing `*` is generally considered bad practice as it might pollute your namespace making you call functions which you didn't expect to.

E.g. imagine a case where you do

```
from numpy import *
from random import *
```

Both `numpy` and `random` offer a function called `random` which means you may not know which you are calling when you call `random()`

Instead import the library into the namespace or import only what you intend to use (linters will tell you about unused imports). In your case you are importing:

- time
- random.random
- PyQt5.QtWidgets

None of which are explicitly used in your code.

#### Case

PEP-8 suggests using `UPPER_SNAKE` for top-level/global variables, `PascalCase` for classes and `lower_snake` for variables and functions.

`shredder`, `filepath` and others don't conform to this.

### Separation of tasks

You have this object called `shredder` which is not just a shredder, it is the GUI to perform shredding. We should split this off and allow it to exist separately from the GUI which may contain a `Shredder`.

You should also have functions which are named to represent what they do. `audio_duration`, for example, doesn't actually care about `audio`, it is just converting a time in seconds to hours, minutes, seconds. You might do one of two things with this, either rename the function to `split_time` or some similar name to describe what it actually does (with docstrings explaining what it does), or make it do what you say it does.

```
def audio_duration(audio: MP3):
    "Gets the duration of an audio track in hours, minutes and seconds"
    length = audio.info.length
    hours = length // 3600  # calculate in hours
    length %= 3600
    mins = length // 60  # calculate in minutes
    length %= 60
    seconds = length  # calculate in seconds

    return hours, mins, seconds  # returns the duration
```

(**N.B.** There exists a `divmod` function to do this operation)

### Comments, docstrings and type hints

Comments and docstrings are useful tools in python for helping other people understand what is going on, however, good comments are not easy to write. Some of your comments only describe what the code is already telling me:

```
    hours = length // 3600  # calculate in hours
```

Is fairly self explanatory, honestly, but a comment saying that it "calculates in hours" is given by the fact that we're assigning it to a variable called hours. What the comment doesn't tell me is what we are calculating from. A better comment (and people will disagree, this is all a matter of taste) might be to explain what calculation you are actually performing.

```
    hours = length // 3600  # Seconds to hours
```

Likewise docstrings are the main tool for other people to use your software. Have you ever typed

```
>>> import random
>>> help(random.randint)
```

The `help` returns the docstring and tells you what the function is supposed to do, what arguments it takes, what it returns and in some cases how the result is reached. Good docstrings are also useful in code to remind yourself of what a function is doing. Again, a good docstring is hard to write, but some tools like sphinx have standard formats which can be helpful in guiding you as to how to write a good one, along with being able to automatically generate the API documentation for your code (without having to write it by hand). A simple docstring might look like

```
def audio_duration(length):
    """Converts duration in seconds to hours, minutes, seconds

    :param length: duration in seconds
    :returns: duration in hours, minutes, seconds
    :rtype: 3-tuple of ints

    """
```

While [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) are optional in Python, they are just another tool in the toolkit to help explain what your code is doing and are often useful to have for yourself and others to see what your code is doing.

### String formats

You are using a mixture of old styles of string formats (`%` formats and `.format`s) the modern style is to use f-strings to make clear what's going on in your code.

```
print('Total Duration Of Song: {}:{}:{}'.format(hours, mins, seconds))
print("In Seconds: " + str(audio.info.length))
print("Creating " + str((audio.info.length//1)+1) + " shreds.")
with open(r"C:\mp3shredder\temp\piece%s.mp3" % i, "wb") as f:
```

become

```
print(f'Total Duration Of Song: {hours}:{mins}:{seconds}')
print(f"In Seconds: {audio.info.length}")
print(f"Creating {audio.info.length//1)+1} shreds.")
with open(rf"C:\mp3shredder\temp\piece{i}.mp3", "wb") as f:
```

### Globals

Avoid using globals, they can cause many problems particularly in larger codes. What happens if you've used a global with a common name like `filepath` and someone else has in their library? Who knows what might happen? It's just problems all around.

Instead just keep things in as local a scope as is feasible. Pass arguments into functions and use them locally. Changes to that argument then won't affect the global state (this is not always the case, be aware of what you change of dummy arguments) and it can be passed in from any name. Say I had 100 files I wanted to `shred`:

```
global filename
for my_file in files_list:
    filename = my_file
    Shredder.shred()
```

or

```
for my_file in filelist:
    Shredder.shred(my_file)
```

Which makes the intent more obvious?

I think that's enough in terms of syntax and structure for now.

Answer (score -1):

You can split mp3 files every 1000 bytes and stitch them together in random order. Here's what will happen: mp3 comes in mp3 blocks of maybe 100-200 bytes. Each block has a four byte header which describes the format of the block and lets you calculate the length. Chances that random 4 bytes match a header are about 1 in 2000. So a player will skip bytes until it finds what looks like a header. Then it calculates the size of the next block according to the header, checks that there is another header at that position, and then you can be reasonably sure you found two real headers, and the MP3 player will start playing. So you have say 10ms of silence at the start.

Since you stitch together 1000 byte blocks without respecting mp3 blocks, you will quite quickly run into a valid block header, followed by some valid bits, followed by invalid bits. Since the player assumes all the bits in an mp3 block are valid, the output will be rubbish. After that, the player recognises that you have no valid header, will skip to the next valid header, and repeat.

The result is that you have randomly reordered music (which is what you wanted), with silence and random rubbish mixed in. It would be much much better to scan through the file, identify the mp3 blocks, and mix them together anyway you like, to avoid the rubbish noises and silences.

Except... There are mp3 variable length modes. Basically, if your blocks should be say 160 bytes each, and one block is nicely compressible and uses only 130 bytes, then the next block uses the last 30 bytes of the previous block and therefore can use 190 instead of 160 bytes. So many blocks use bytes from the previous block. If this is used then you need to extract all the blocks, and determine which bytes each block really contains (add bytes it uses from the previous block, subtract bytes used from the next block). And then you can rearrange the blocks, and try to recreate them so that each block uses the data bytes it should, as far as you can. This won't be perfect, but better than not doing it.

A simpler way is to take the file, decode it, rearrange it in blocks of say 50 milliseconds, and re-encode the output to mp3. You will have lossy encoding, but nobody will notice in your scrambled music.

Do NOT encode small chunks, because each time you do this a random amount of silence is added. An mp3 file is *always* a whole range of blocks of about 20-25ms. Rearrange the audio signal in memory instead, then encode the complete file. And you cannot just concatenate mp3 files because that will duplicate all the meta information.

Comment: `AudioSegment.from_mp3` does, in fact, decode an mp3 file, and slicing the resulting object does, in fact, slice it based on time and not bytes